# Unity3D How can I select multiple objects in 3D with a drag and select / lasso select?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, collision-detection, multipleselection

I am struggling to find a good tutorial or informations that would allow me to select multiple objects in 3D in a user friendly manner.

So far, the best tutorial I found is this one : https://sharpcoderblog.com/blog/unity-3d-rts-style-unit-selection. The tutorial works by using the transform.position of the selectable objects and checking if it within the user's selection.

What I wish is to have the user be able to select a unit even if it is only partially within the user's selection such as most RTS games do ( both in 2D and 3D ).

One possibility would be to create a temporary mesh using the camera's clipping distances and the user's selection and then check for collisions but I was not able to find any tutorials using this method nor do I know if it is the best approach to the subject.

Comment: I think this is a good starting point: [How to make free area selection](https://answers.unity.com/questions/459426/how-to-make-free-area-selectionlike-lasso-tool-in.html)

Comment: it looks promising thanks, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to

- somehow start a selection
- collect every object that was "hit" during the collection
- somehow end the collection

Couldn't you simply use raycasting? I will assume simple mouse input for now but you could basically port this to whatever input you have.

```c#
// Just a little helper class for an event in the Inspector you can add listeners to
[SerializeField]
public class SelectionEvent : UnityEvent<HashSet<GameObject>> { }

public class SelectionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Adjust via the Inspector and select layers that shall be selectable
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask includeLayers;

    // Add your custom callbacks here either via code or the Inspector
    public SelectionEvent OnSelectionChanged;
 
    // Collects the current selection   
    private HashSet<GameObject> selection = new HashSet<GameObject>();
    // Stores the current Coroutine controlling he selection process
    private Coroutine selectionRoutine;

    // If possible already reference via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Camera _mainCamera;

    // Otherwise get it once on runtime
    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!_mainCamera) _mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }

    // Depending on how exactly you want to start and stop the selection     
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartSelection();
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            EndSelection();
        }
    }
    
    public void StartSelection()
    {
        // if there is already a selection running you don't wanr to start another one
        if(selectionRoutine != null) return;
    
        selectionRoutine = StartCoroutine (SelectionRoutine ());
    }
    
    public void EndSelection()
    {
        // If there is no selection running then you can't end one
        if(selectionRoutine == null) return;
    
        StopCoroutine (selectionRoutine);
        selectionRoutine = null;
    
        // Inform all listeners about the new selection
        OnSelectionChanged.Invoke(new HashSet<GameObject>(selection);
    }
    
    private IEnumerator SelectionRoutine()
    {
        // Start with an empty selection
        selection.Clear();
        
        // This is ok in a Coroutine as long as you yield somewhere within it
        while(true)
        {
            // Get the ray shooting forward from the camera at the mouse position
            // for other inputs simply replace this according to your needs
            var ray = _mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
         
            // Check if you hit any object   
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, layerMask = includeLayers ))
            {
                // If so Add it once to your selection
                if(!selection.Contains(hit.gameObject)) selection.Add(hit.gameObject);
            }
    
            // IMPORTANT: Tells Unity to "pause" here, render this frame
            // and continue from here in the next frame
            // (without this your app would freeze in an endless loop!)
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Ofcourse you could do it directly in `Update` in this example but I wanted to provide it in a way where you can easily exchange the input method according to your needs ;)

From UX side you additionally might want to call a second event like `OnSelectionPreviewUpdate` or something like this every time you add a new object to the selection in order to be able to e.g. visualize the selection outcome.

---

I might have understood this wrong and it sounds like you rather wanted to get everything inside of a drawn shape.

This is slightly more complex but here would be my idea for that:

- Have a dummy selection Rigidbody object that by default is disabled and does nothing
- don't even have a renderer on it but a mesh filter and mesh collider
- while you "draw" create a mesh based on the input
- then use [`Rigidbody.SweepTestAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.SweepTestAll.html) in order to check if you hit anything with it

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am struggling to understand how it would allow me to select multiple objects within a given area ( lasso selection / drag and select ). My understanding is that this would allow me to add anything on the condition the mouse hovers over it but would not allow to select all of the objects on a screen if I dragged the mouse from one corner to an other

Comment: @MatthieuRaynauddeFitte yes sorry just understood your question ^^ At first I thought you want a hover selection. Right now I'm out of time ;) I briefly added my idea as an edit but right now I cant implement it yet .. as said only on the phone :)

Comment: No problem, thank you for your time :) I indeed did not look into raycast enough, I will check if I can't find anything more in the raycast doc

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try to create a PolygonCollider2D because it is quite simple comparing to creating a mesh. You can set its path (outline) by giving it 2D points like location of your pointer/mouse. Use the [SetPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.SetPath.html) method for it. You can then use one of its methods to check if another point in space overlaps with that collider shape.

While the PolygonCollider2D interacts with 2D components you can still use its `Collider2D.OverlapPoint` method to check positions/bounds of your 3D objects after translating it to 2D space.

You can also use its `CreateMesh` method to create a mesh for drawing your selection area on the screen.

You can read more about the PolygonCollider2D [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html).

Hope it makes sens and hope it helps.